# How to exit on current bar open?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy that I am testing on a 15-second chart. My entries are going fine, and the trail stop is also fine. I have coded that the strategy will exit at the start of the next 5-minute candle. However, it was exiting at the next open. I want to exit at 12:30:00, but the exit is happening at 12:30:15.

Exit at next candle open:

[image: Exit at next candle open]

I have seen that there was an "immediate" argument, but putting that to true is making the exit to be at the candle close (basically, 12:30:15 again).

Exit at current candle close:

[image: Exit at current candle close]

How do I either make it exit at the current candle open or shift the description for `timeframe` change so that the exit is triggered at the previous candle (Exit at 12:30:00, so trigger at 12:29:45 for the next candle open)? The relevant sections of the code I want to change are given below:

```
i_tf = input.timeframe("5", "Higher TimeFrame")

new_higher_tf = timeframe.change(i_tf)

if strategy.position_size > 0 and new_higher_tf
    strategy.close("Long", immediately=true, comment = "Long_Exit", alert_message = comment_lx)

if strategy.position_size < 0 and new_higher_tf
    strategy.close("Short", immediately=true, comment = "Short_Exit", alert_message = comment_sx)
```

I have tried to see if I can get precision in timeframe change so that I can trigger at 45 seconds every 5 minutes (or even 1 minute), but I don't seem to be able to find anything close to what I require.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `calc_on_every_tick`,
which makes the strategy recalculate entries and exits on each tick:

```
strategy(title="My Strategy", calc_on_every_tick=true)
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the trade still exits on the close of the candle.